# Should I "Vote To Close" In This Instance?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

A [c++] question was posted recently that had been asked before.  By the time I saw the question there were 2 votes to close and a link to a duplicate question.  I looked at the dupe's accepted answer, and I disagree with it.  I think there's a better answer.

Should I vote to close?  Answer the new question?  Answer the dupe?  Something else?

Comment: Maybe I don't get something about meta, but why in he** was this downvoted

Comment: Couldn't say, but I found the title confusing. Like you were suggesting closing a question because *it* had an accepted answer you didn't like rather than asking about the proper fate of a duplicate when the original had the squirrelly response.

Comment: my usual response here would be to just link to [How does Meta Stack Overflow work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work), but that doesn't seem quite applicable here. Perhaps the downvoter thought you were advocating one of those positions? +1 from me, at any rate.

Comment: I edited the title to be less explicit, but hopefully less confusing

Answer (score 5):

Vote to close the new question and answer the original question.

Comment: And you could write a comment in the new, soon-to-be-closed question to that effect. 'Cause if you're right you want people to see and judge your different answer. There could be a "populist" badge in your future.

Comment: Or even a Necromancer.